# не отображаются изображения в html письме для рассылки

Tags: html, email

Кто может подсказать в чем проблема, я сверстал email рассылку, изображения залил на Yandex диск, в gmail и rambler почте в письме не отображаются изображения, только пустые блоки под них и значок битой ссылки, отправлял письма не через агент рассылки а клик по полю для сообщения edit as html , туда и вставлял код. когда код вставлен , в поле для сообщения само письмо отображается корректно, но после отправки приходит без изображений.

Comment: а где код письма и код отправки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того, чтобы избежать этой проблемы вставляйте не путь к изображению, а Base64 (то есть по сути само содержимое).

В итоге изображения будут выглядеть примерно так:

`<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/*строка данных base64*/" />`

Тут может быть не `jpg`, а другие расширения.

К примеру, картинку надо задавать не через путь:

`<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8BTI.jpg" />`

А через Base64:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Существует немало сервисов, которые позволяют превращать заданную картинку в Base64.